# How delete element.nativeElement from DOM?

Tags: angular, angular5

I tried this way:

```js
    @ViewChild('draggable') private draggableElement: ElementRef;

    this.draggableElement.nativeElement.remove();
```

HTML:

```html
    <div #draggable>Block</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to programmatically remove a DOM element using Angular?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your code can also work, all you have to do is remove element on **OnInit()**, If you try to remove elements on constructor, the view not be ready.

here's is an example

in **.html**

```html
    <div #draggable>Block</div>
```

and in **.ts**

```js
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      name="Angular";
    
      @ViewChild('draggable') private draggableElement: ElementRef;
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
       this.draggableElement.nativeElement.remove();
      }
    }
```

here's is an [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-renderer2-remove-pucs2c?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) demo

Answer (score 3):

User Renderer2 service to remove element from dom

> removeChild() Implement this callback to remove a child node from the
> host element's DOM.

```js
@ViewChild('draggable')  draggableElement: ElementRef;
constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2,private el:ElementRef) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.renderer2.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement,this.draggableElement.nativeElement);
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-renderer2-remove

Answer (score 1):

You can use *ngIf right, which will be removed from the DOM when condition fails.

Block

Comment: I asked another question, not about ngIf

Comment: A little thing against using `*ngIf` but if you're using it, you will not be able to use that element togheter with `@ViewChild()` in the `ngOnInit` since the element isn't existing at that time.

Answer (score -1):

If you shall neither not use `*ngIf` nor `nativeElement` because what you try to remove is a component I would recommend you to remove the component with pure javascript.

```html
<your-component id="draggable" #draggable>Block</your-component>
```

```js
document.getElementById('draggable').remove()
```

*If you want to do it in an angular manner, then you would have to use [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef). that method is explained in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69679825/11135174)*